# Formulario con en 3 pasos persistencia de datos

Tags: asp.net

Tengo que hacer un formulario con 3 pasos, en cada paso antes de pasar al siguiente hay que grabar los datos por si se vuelve atrás que aparezcan los que ya se han rellenado.
La idea es hacer 3 vistas ( 3 paginas ) una por cada paso del formulario.

- ¿Cómo puedo guardar los datos para que no se pierdan cuando paso a la siguiente pagina?
- ¿Se puede hacer una clase estática que los guarda ?
- ¿ Se debe hacer mejor con sesiones?

Comment: Te recomiendo leer [ask] ya que tu pregunta es muy amplia y se basa en opiniones, motivos por los cuales terminará cerrada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias dejar esos datos en el browser del cliente, con **WebStorage**

https://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html5_webstorage.asp

Ejemplo de uso:

https://decodigoyalgomas.com/como-almacenar-json-en-localstorage/

Tambien dejando las variables en la **Session** del usuario,

https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/6ad7zeeb(v=vs.100).aspx

La otra seria guardarlo en **Base de datos, o Cache**, pero para tu caso no lo recomendaría.

En cuanto a las clases estáticas, podrías generar una variable que persista los datos, pero al estar en un entorno web deberías crear una por cada usuario que use el formulario o un arreglo de estos y ... mientras menos carga tenga el servidor web, mejor así que no se recomendaría en este caso.

Saludos.

Comment: Actualmente estoy usando asp con web form con framework3.5 ¿ Tienes algún pequeño ejemplo que pueda probar ?

Comment: Ahi te deje un ejemplo de uso de WebStorage, lo haces con javascript.

Comment: Muchas Gracias. Mi otra pregunta era si es posible en asp con c# y web forms crear una clase estatica y que esta guarde los datos a medida que voy cambiando de vista ( de pagina HTML ) ?

Comment: La idea general es una pregunta a la vez.
En cuanto a las clases estáticas, ahi modifique la respuesta.

Comment: No se deben responder preguntas tan amplías y que no muestran dudas específicas sobre código, te recomiendo leer [answer]

Comment: Muchas gracias de nuevo por tu ayuda

Comment: No hay problema.
Como mencionaron arriba, trata de no hacer preguntas tan amplias, y en lo posible mas objetivas, de esta forma perdemos menos tiempo interpretando,
Saludos.

Comment: pues es que si se siguieran las reglas, no habria por que estar interpretando